# MariaDB 10.6: How much undo does my query generate?

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.6, undo

For reasons, I'm trying to work out just how much undo any single query generates.

I know how to get this in Oracle DB, but don't know if it's possible in MariaDB/MySQL.

Is it possible, and how?

MariaDB 10.6.

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is rather general.,  So here is a rather general Answer:  A copy of each modified row is saved for Undo.

Comment: It's general yes, but it is a general question. Given any query that I can run, is it possible to identify the volume of undo that it has generated?

Comment: @PhilSumner - I don't think there is any metric, at least not any reliable metric.  For example, watching disk space is unreliable because each extra row copy will usually fill in free space; only occasionally will it do a block split, thereby consuming 16KB.